# How to get floating point results from an SQL query?

Tags: sql, qt, double

I have successfully connected to my database, but when I select 2 cells from my SQL db to set the value for both of my variables it does nothing. I have no problem inserting data into the database. I have tried different approaches to this with no success. Could it be that I am trying to use a string format for doubles??

```
double userHeight;
double userWeight;
QSqlQuery query;
QString retreiveUserHeight = 
    QString("SELECT Height, Weight FROM SQL1 WHERE Username='joejoe'");
query.prepare(retreiveUserHeight);
query.bindValue(0,"Height");
query.bindValue(1, "Weight");
query.exec();
userHeight = query.value(0).toInt();
userWeight = query.value(1).toInt();
```

I'm pretty certain there is a small error in syntax that is causing this mishap but I have been unable to find it. Thanks for your help.

```
qDebug() << "calculated" << 703*(userWeight/(userHeight*userHeight)) 
         << userWeight << userHeight ;
```

Heres the debug output:

```
calculated nan 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Obtain username from somewhere
QString username = "joejoe";


// Check whether DB is open
if( db->isOpen( ) )
{
    QSqlQuery query;

    double userHeight;
    double userWeight;


    // Prepare select statement
    query.prepare   ( "SELECT Height , Weight FROM SQL1 WHERE Username = :username" );
    query.bindValue ( ":username" , username );
    query.exec      ( );

    // Check if something went wrong when executing your query
    if( query.lastError( ).text( ).trimmed( ) == "" )
    {
        // Loop through all results and handle them accordingly
        while( query.next( ) )
        {
             userHeight = query.value( 0 ).toDouble( );
             userWeight = query.value( 1 ).toDouble( );

             qDebug( ) << "calculated" << 703 * ( userWeight / ( userHeight * userHeight ) ) << userWeight << userHeight;
             qDebug( ) << "---------------------------------";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Display the error that occured
        QMessageBox::critical( this , tr( "SQL Error" ) , query.lastError( ).text( ) );
    }
}
```

I assume this is what you wanted it to look like.

I've included some error checking and corrected your query to use `.bindValue( )` correctly, since it's not meant for using for return values rather than for input as seen in the `WHERE`.

Since I don't know anything about your sql table I've included a loop to go through all results of your query. That can obviously be changed.

Apart from that if you're using `double`s you should cast the result `.toDouble( )` rather than `.toInt( )`

Comment: Your solution works perfectly and is username specific.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of serious problems with this code. Let's start with the concept of prepared SQL queries. Wikipedia lists [two reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for using prepared statements:

- The overhead of compiling and optimizing the statement is incurred
  only once, although the statement is executed multiple times. [...]
- Prepared statements are resilient against SQL injection, because
  parameter values, which are transmitted later using a different
  protocol, need not be correctly escaped.

Neither of these reasons apply in your code; you're only executing the query once, and you're not splicing any inputs into the string. In fact, the only input in your query at all is the username, which is hard-coded to `"joejoe"`:

```
"SELECT Height, Weight FROM SQL1 WHERE Username='joejoe'"
```

Since there are no variable inputs, using a prepared query doesn't make much sense. Neither do the following lines:

```
query.bindValue(0,"Height");
query.bindValue(1, "Weight");
```

Height and Weight are *outputs* from this query, not *inputs*. See the section in the [Qt docs for QSqlQuery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html) titled "Approaches to Binding Values" for an explanation of how this is intended to work. Qt's API for binding prepared SQL queries is fairly typical among database libraries, there's nothing earth shattering here.

Then we get to this:

```
userHeight = query.value(0).toInt();
userWeight = query.value(1).toInt();
```

Both the variables you're reading into here were declared as doubles, but you're calling `toInt()` on the returned `QVariant` rather than [toDouble()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toDouble). I don't know what (if any!) values are in your database, but it's possible they're getting rounded down to zero during the conversion from double to int if the values are between -1.0 and 1.0.

That said, you aren't doing any error checking whatsoever. The methods `prepare()` and `exec()` return bools that indicate whether they succeeded or failed. Likewise, both `toInt()` and `toDouble()` tell you whether they've succeeded or failed if you pass in a pointer to a bool. It's worth noting that both methods also return a zero value on failure.